# Can't make a simple Login to PHP Form Centos 8 Nginx 1.41

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, centos8

I have an Nginx web server installed on Centos 8, suddenly after I enable execute PHP in HTML in Nginx configuration I can't log in to some scripts installed like FileRun or ProjectSend or a simple PHP form I created, what I got is when I enter the right login info, the web Page reload that is it and not redirect to the main page or next page after login, I tried to back everything as it was and it still not working.
What I did exactly to Enable executing PHP in HTML is

1. change this line location ~ .php$ to location ~ .(php|html|htm)$ {
2. after that I go to /etc/php-fpm/www.conf and add this line security.limit_extensions =
3. restart both Nginx and PHP-FPM and PHP works fine in HTML

This is the last change I did on my Nginx server and the full Nginx Configuration I use

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    return         301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    root /home/mydomain/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    access_log /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.com_access_log;
    error_log /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.com_error_log;
    client_max_body_size 4096M;
    fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/mydomain/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/mydomain/public_html;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;
    location ~ \.(php|html|htm)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
    }
    
    location /downloads {
        autoindex on;
    }
    
    location /license {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /license/index.php; 
    }
    
    listen ip:443 default ssl;
    ssl_certificate /home/mydomain/ssl.combined;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/mydomain/ssl.key;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
}
```

and what I got from the firefox developer tool (Network) is 2 requests with status `302 Found` then it redirects to the same index.php and not make me go to the main page after login.

I don't know what happened but I really stuck at this point and can't find a solution, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by making the `/var/lib/php` folder give it `0777` permission I don't know what makes it change its permission suddenly, but this folder contains folder name `session` which was causing the problem make this folder not writable make the web apps not save the sessions so it not record session and cookies this is why no login was redirect to the main dashboard ..etc you can check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937138/cookies-dont-work-apache-to-nginx)