# net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED on remote server when there are more than 7 sub-documents in mongo document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssl, nginx, http2

I am developing a MEAN project with angular 4.1.0.

On my localhost, everything works without errors. When I deploy to the server however, retrieving a user with more than 8 question-answer pairs causes a **net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED** error on the **xhr** request that angular's http module fires.

The digital ocean droplet I am hosting on uses an nginx reverse proxy and uses a letsencrypt SSL certificate. 
I have tried:

- Restarting server, nginx service, node.js etc.
- Increasing `client_max_body_size` to `20M` in the nginx config file
- Increasing `large_client_header_buffers`' size to `128k` in the nginx config file

Other important facts:

- The `GET` request to `qapairs?jwt=ey..` never reaches the node.js app
- There is no mention of the request in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`
- The failing requests shown in the `/var/log/nginx/access.log` are as follows:

  ```
  89.15.159.19 - - [08/May/2017:14:25:53 +0000] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
  89.15.159.19 - - [08/May/2017:14:25:53 +0000] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
  ```

Please point me in possible directions.

---

## The chrome dev tool network tab screenshots

1. **After logging in to an account where there are only 7 question answer pairs**
   [image: After logging in to an account where there are only 7 question answer pairs]
2. **Then, after going to mlab.com and manually adding another question answer pair to same account and then refreshing the page (notice the number of questions in now 8)**
   [image: After going to mlab.com and manually adding another question answer pair to same account and then refreshing the page]
3. **Finally, after logging in and out of the same account (notice the xhr request to `qapairs?jwt=ey...` returned a failed status)**
   [image: After logging in and out of the same account]

> ***/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default***
>
> ```
> # HTTP — redirect all traffic to HTTPS
> server {
>     listen 80;
>     listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
>     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
> }
>
> # etc
>
> # HTTPS  ^ ^  proxy all requests to the Node app
> server {
>     # Enable HTTP/2
>     listen 443 ssl http2;
>     listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
>     server_name subdomain.example.com;
>
>     # Use the Let ^ ^ s Encrypt certificates
>     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
>     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
>
>     # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
>     include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
>
>     # Increase allowed URL length     
>     large_client_header_buffers 4 128k;
>
>     # Increase max body size
>     client_max_body_size 20M;
>
>     location / {
>         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
>         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>         proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
>         proxy_pass http://subdomain.example.com:3001/;
>         proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
>         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
>         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
>         proxy_redirect off;
>     }
> }
> ```

---

> ***qa-pairs.service.ts***
>
> **The error is being caught here in the `getQAPairs` function. Being passed to the callback in the `catch` function a `ProgressEvent` object with a `type` property of
>   `error`, `eventPhase` of `2`.**
>
> ```
> @Injectable()
> export class QaPairsService {
>   /* etc */
>
>   getQAPairs () {
>     const jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt') ? `?jwt=${localStorage.getItem('jwt')}` : ''
>
>     return this.http.get(this.qapairsUrl + jwt)
>       .map(response => {
>         this.qapairs = response.json().map((qapair: IQAPair) => new QAPair(qapair))
>         this.qapairsChanged.emit(this.qapairs)
>         return this.qapairs
>       })
>       .catch(
>         (error: any) => {
>           error = error.json()
>           this.errorsService.handleError(error)
>           return Observable.throw(error)
>         }
>       )
>   }
>
>   /* etc */
> }
> ```

Comment: You are asking a good question, but at least try to filter in only the relevant parts of the code.
I assume you debugged some of it, and have a general understanding between what stages the error occurs.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will do this first thing tomorrow

Comment: @OmriLuzon Please see the amended answer

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Solution:

> ***/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default***
>
> ```
> # other code here
>
> server {
>
>    # other code here
>
>    # Increase http2 max sizes
>    http2_max_field_size 64k;
>    http2_max_header_size 64k;
>
> }
> ```

The reason I found this so hard to debug was because there was

> no mention of the request in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

and I didn't realize that nginx has the ability to be [more verbose with its logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17289826/5950725) (duh)

So after changing `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` to include

```
server { 
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log info;
}
```

I saw

```
2017/05/08 16:17:04 [info] 3037#3037: *9 client exceeded http2_max_field_size limit while processing HTTP/2 connection, client: 89.15.159.19, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

which was the error message I needed.

Comment: Your a literal life saver. Have been stuck at this for days now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Same, I was getting 504 Gateway Errors, ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED, and all manner of weird errors without increasing these. Thanks!

Comment: This saved my life! For anyone using a newer version of nginx, these lines should do the trick instead:  client_header_buffer_size 1k; large_client_header_buffers 4 4k;

Answer (score 0):

This helped me!!! Unfortunately there were no error messages.
It helps me:

```
client_header_buffer_size 1k; large_client_header_buffers 4 4k;
```