# Nginx Client SSL certification validation

Tags: c#, ssl, nginx

I am very new to Nginx and I need your help/suggestions in resolving below issue.

I have configured Nginx as a reverse proxy on windows server 2012 r2 and trying to route calls to my Backend server 'SERVERA' whenever request is made to Nginx.

My requirement is like, I need to pass a client certificate to Nginx server and if the certficate is valid then route the calls to backend server 'SERVERA' else it should reject call at Nginx.

I have made changes to the config file on Nginx server like below to configure client certification validation.

```
server {
        listen       443 ssl; 
        server_name  localhost;

        ssl_certificate      "C:/NewCert/server.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key  "C:/NewCert/server.key";
        ssl_client_certificate "C:/NewCert/ca.crt";

        ssl_verify_client on;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass https://SERVERA/MyWebService;
        }

        location /MyWebService {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass https://SERVERA/MyWebService;
        }
   }
```

I have generated the client and server certificates as stated in the below post and used the same for Nginx server configuration
"http://nategood.com/client-side-certificate-authentication-in-ngi"

After the above config changes on the Nginx server whenever I try to browse the service I get "400 Bad request"
"https://localhost/MyWebService"

When I make a call from client using client certificate to Nginx server I get below error.

> "{System.Net.WebException: Error: SecureChannelFailure (A call to SSPI
>   failed, see inner exception.) --->
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI
>   failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Syscall
>   at Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsContext.ProcessHandshake () [0x00038] in
>   :0    at
>   Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake
>   (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x0003e] in
>   :0    at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake(Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus)
>   at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncHandshakeRequest.Run
>   (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x00006] in
>   :0    at
>   Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest+d__24.MoveNext
>   () "

Below is my client code

```
namespace Test 
{
class SomeTest
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        try
          {
            string urlString = @"https://SERVERA/MyWebService";
            MyWebClient obj = new MyWebClient();
            obj.UploadData(urlString, new byte[2]);
          }
        catch (Exception ex)
          {
            string st = ex.Message;
          }
    }
}
class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);

        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate x509Certificate = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate(@"/storage/emulated/0/nginx.crt");
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(x509Certificate);
        request.Method = "POST";
        return request;
    }
}
}
```

Any Help/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Vinod

Comment: See codeproject: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326574/An-Introduction-to-Mutual-SSL-Authentication

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315832/how-to-fix-nginx-throws-400-bad-request-headers-on-any-header-testing-tools).

Comment: I get below message in the error log.

client sent no required SSL certificate while reading client request headers, client: x.x.x.x, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "y.y.y.y", referrer: "https://y.y.y.y/"

Answer (score 1):

try this in nginx config:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
server {
    listen       443 ssl; 
    server_name  localhost;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    ssl_certificate      "C:/NewCert/server.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key  "C:/NewCert/server.key";
    ssl_client_certificate "C:/NewCert/ca.crt";

    ssl_verify_client optional;

    location / {
        if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
            return 403;
        }
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass https://SERVERA/MyWebService;
    }

    location /MyWebService {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass https://SERVERA/MyWebService;
    }
```

}