# Nginx .Net Core POST 400 Bad Request

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, .net-core

I have an app that is located in a subdirectory on my local docker. When I submit a form via POST, I get a 400 Bad Request error.

I noticed that it doesnt go to my .NET Core app. Instead, the error lies with nginx.

I managed to extract some logs showing the Bad Request. However, I am unable to see the cause of it:

```
    Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 22 Oct 2022 16:45:31 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055E39DBBB450, pos 000055E39DBBB450, size: 346 file: 0, size: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:346
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http cacheable: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy filter init s:200 h:0 c:0 l:-1
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http upstream process upstream
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe read upstream: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe preread: 90
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe buf free s:0 t:1 f:0 000055E39DC2DEF0, pos 000055E39DC2DFDC, size: 90 file: 0, size: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe length: -1
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe write downstream: 1
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe write busy: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe write: out:0000000000000000, f:0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe read upstream: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe buf free s:0 t:1 f:0 000055E39DC2DEF0, pos 000055E39DC2DFDC, size: 90 file: 0, size: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe length: -1
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 event timer: 21, old: 8980200, new: 8980256
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http upstream request: "/Manage/Message/AnnouncementAttachment/Search?"
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http upstream dummy handler
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http upstream request: "/Manage/Message/AnnouncementAttachment/Search?"
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http upstream process upstream
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe read upstream: 1
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 readv: eof:1, avail:-1
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 readv: 1, last:16058
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe recv chain: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe buf free s:0 t:1 f:0 000055E39DC2DEF0, pos 000055E39DC2DFDC, size: 90 file: 0, size: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe length: -1
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 input buf #0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe write downstream: 1
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe write downstream flush in
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http output filter "/Manage/Message/AnnouncementAttachment/Search?"
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http copy filter: "/Manage/Message/AnnouncementAttachment/Search?"
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http postpone filter "/Manage/Message/AnnouncementAttachment/Search?" 000055E39DBC47F0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http chunk: 90
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055E39DBBB450, pos 000055E39DBBB450, size: 346 file: 0, size: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055E39DBC4C28, pos 000055E39DBC4C28, size: 4 file: 0, size: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055E39DC2DEF0, pos 000055E39DC2DFDC, size: 90 file: 0, size: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 000055E39CE886FA, size: 2 file: 0, size: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:442
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http copy filter: 0 "/Manage/Message/AnnouncementAttachment/Search?"
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe write downstream done
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 event timer: 21, old: 8980200, new: 8980256
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http upstream exit: 0000000000000000
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 finalize http upstream request: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 finalize http proxy request
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 free rr peer 1 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 close http upstream connection: 21
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 free: 000055E39DBB4010, unused: 48
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 event timer del: 21: 8980200
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 reusable connection: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http upstream temp fd: -1
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http output filter "/Manage/Message/AnnouncementAttachment/Search?"
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http copy filter: "/Manage/Message/AnnouncementAttachment/Search?"
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http postpone filter "/Manage/Message/AnnouncementAttachment/Search?" 00007FFD0E8F95E0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http chunk: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055E39DBBB450, pos 000055E39DBBB450, size: 346 file: 0, size: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055E39DBC4C28, pos 000055E39DBC4C28, size: 4 file: 0, size: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055E39DC2DEF0, pos 000055E39DC2DFDC, size: 90 file: 0, size: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 write old buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 000055E39CE886FA, size: 2 file: 0, size: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 000055E39CE886F7, size: 5 file: 0, size: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:447
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http write filter limit 2097152
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 writev: 447 of 447
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http write filter 0000000000000000
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http copy filter: 0 "/Manage/Message/AnnouncementAttachment/Search?"
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http finalize request: 0, "/Manage/Message/AnnouncementAttachment/Search?" a:1, c:1
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 set http keepalive handler
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http close request
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 http log handler
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 free: 000055E39DC2DEF0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 free: 000055E39DBB0DE0, unused: 2
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 free: 000055E39DBC3C50, unused: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 free: 000055E39DBBA420, unused: 8
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 free: 000055E39DBBB430, unused: 2844
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 free: 000055E39DB9A1B0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 hc free: 0000000000000000
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 hc busy: 000055E39DBB4368 1
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 free: 000055E39DC1DEE0
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 reusable connection: 1
2022/10/22 16:45:31 [debug] 25#25: *3 event timer add: 20: 65000:8985256
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http keepalive handler
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 malloc: 000055E39DB9A1B0:1024
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 recv: fd:20 1024 of 1024
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 recv: avail:5158
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 reusable connection: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 posix_memalign: 000055E39DBB0DE0:4096 @16
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 event timer del: 20: 8985256
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http process request line
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http request line: "POST /Manage/Message/Announcement/Update HTTP/1.1"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http uri: "/Manage/Message/Announcement/Update"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http args: ""
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http exten: ""
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 posix_memalign: 000055E39DBC3C50:4096 @16
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http process request header line
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "Host: localhost:9190"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "Connection: keep-alive"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "Content-Length: 2304"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "Cache-Control: max-age=0"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="106", "Google Chrome";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99""
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows""
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "Origin: http://localhost:9190"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "Sec-Fetch-User: ?1"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "Sec-Fetch-Dest: document"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "Referer: http://localhost:9190/Manage/Message/Announcement/Edit/a4f91c12-ebd3-4c98-9544-41d3757770bf"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http alloc large header buffer
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 malloc: 000055E39DC1DEE0:65536
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http large header alloc: 000055E39DC1DEE0 65536
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http large header copy: 96
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 recv: eof:0, avail:5158
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 recv: fd:20 5158 of 65440
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 recv: avail:0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header: "Cookie: SDR-Application-AFT=CfDJ8FbhNDhYUKNOn7v_odQ8fUMEWWc8ux9dasp9_SfryYplsUPdrV7Z2zTvjYcuzfecjPsjKDAVhDfYiEUrFxBrAOakXhoJDIr8mFevfahkdJPzzCntkqrgt8KY4aIRD6olFZAlHF83TPH3fbL4EHpxBUU; SDR-Application-AFT=CfDJ8MzjMVmpnLpKi5exDubmXfStXUVh1gFAfTk287t86Xy7bocYw6WhG7jiTnmMsSrpJiDg07UjE3fWjt1IVEO7qBUBpDqKW3rHjfJry65-3RDGlw1RmeD4Dz-gAlJB8w6ymX5-O7HuHQO0KfNpQoFWtDE; CUID=c28c3aee-8b3f-4225-9bc4-55002813c7e5_947d7b34-d6be-4083-8388-57276f3fbfb0; CSID=g3qL9RL3%2FXXInBEf%2FBNbXzpO2HdORePUKccHrAaoVA2JJug%2Bwy9U%2BGr%2F%2FlF5SJoigJP2cniHq%2FMha1eAJqNktU8KBvCXEqKA0%2Fst3lKBgvmW%2FY91KSP1G3Fag78mJ2KB10H1TKPENCTgCYb5f%2Fe9xpTKNrHsMApWYJuRRPgj%2BrD2OOCKgtXzF1%2Frg36nywL0VuYz5f%2BLdZID5I2Wy6jDyMz%2BpTqiKi0jyQBBr6vE6Dfau704cNfh1YL89fabPsi3NY2bFjcf13GhzOcWJQ6CWrEqQUPWl%2B9or2D%2Bly0JL%2F8z3VDCd%2FHasLpCUhD7ZcCmxv15R8rnjP8TgqgU1Rh4HyxiK3wVgIINeP%2FtQscUKpLfxPwjrSxNQzZox5LzxYFCBhtjDNybTcqqySuosCtUk%2BWYeP5KymiBq4s%2Bs9cZteG1R6faVaGDfKUSEye2GxLgtLScXlwVf%2BaWkjDtrgNzGteQNKoevyYHZePVMqBBIww8alxm2mE9wPZjj2pyaFsZzsCwt1oWnUzSXFFkjys9KUiRpB%2FWghYUUENKSRxC%2BmHZ7VfCMFRaEmmIo3oGNx%2FfKWGP5n1nM9L52t%2BpKQfY4F0QKQZQgAQUkmbqjvU7TYV8cEb9ns%2BUqw%2FtKOih9VfmKZ35xruNqoE%2B2bGTBQEA0ynT%2FGVM%2BIPvB7BlhpHr1lAoSqNxiP6%2FhG8gMBmGJvndeu7nn51mS1yep8NCXIpRwHx4nXyNEMdqEsSm4QfCdbxkNHbeA%2Bb6CrCEOPhn5o6eeltTb7Yo%2FElyQpeXC0gpbq44W2pXZci41CLqVNDTyomn%2B2hPqSzys1VW4cGi0Mk%2BL%2BcJCmGZXKmaw69iQ6CVXRVhGLhmjWIAnOs%2BO0%2FX43otgO8nhl99H%2FG83ngyvn5E78tN9XvHu2rYqTr89lg%2FpaLJ7etwN5kqPR2GI3UZ8d6w1uSw84lcj2S%2FcLg39aIqpqomm8blSGaAMVri0YiL0YwLemCu2m%2FOz5pKzeDkQgw10ieaeBIdT9OsCnxsPkHne4SiyraBpdbkUaJ0JeBZNQ%3D%3D; CTID=hhWjy3FtBI%2B%2BH34KhCfrwNqmsS96AeOqezXSpiguvcfWT6Vj1QtNuwUCIvIZCmebzvP2JTsKx6oDNfcL7TigYjY8PMj%2BBXnEAvRtsQ0KAwiGUq236NOWkTj5rurGdiwOvotKMfW4RJZyOYXwin%2FkZvBKTGoh5ZY%2Bw5GKkwH0h9An6cq2zJ6EWhKNHCg8EdTqzvBNwYMSme1TrYBorlE19RXQJttrn4w08ltZiys0u3o6%2BJ%2FhsMrqMnQaa%2BKUfNfaC2k46NzZQKL4Kbpv6pBLEtDdc9iJKKU%2BHFUXdRifIPiItlHwZK97lqDAyqPhY83evnF7eL5HyvY7B7RLk6eum5OK2HQaHsaK%2FNU2VO95KOMQFG2yhIpAfmDrXeKS%2F
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http header done
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 generic phase: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 rewrite phase: 1
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 test location: "/"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 test location: "Gateway/"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 test location: "Manage/"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 using configuration "/Manage/"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http cl:2304 max:1048576
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 rewrite phase: 3
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 post rewrite phase: 4
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 generic phase: 5
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 generic phase: 6
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 generic phase: 7
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 access phase: 8
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 access phase: 9
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 access phase: 10
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 post access phase: 11
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 generic phase: 12
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 generic phase: 13
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http client request body preread 2304
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http request body content length filter
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http body new buf t:1 f:0 000055E39DC1EA66, pos 000055E39DC1EA66, size: 2304 file: 0, size: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http init upstream, client timer: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 posix_memalign: 000055E39DBBA420:4096 @16
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http script copy: ""
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http script copy: "Host"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http script var: "manage_us"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http script copy: "Connection"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http script copy: "close"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http script copy: "Content-Length"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http script var: "2304"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http script copy: ""
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "Cache-Control: max-age=0"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="106", "Google Chrome";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99""
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows""
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "Origin: http://localhost:9190"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "Sec-Fetch-User: ?1"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "Sec-Fetch-Dest: document"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "Referer: http://localhost:9190/Manage/Message/Announcement/Edit/a4f91c12-ebd3-4c98-9544-41d3757770bf"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "Cookie: SDR-Application-AFT=CfDJ8FbhNDhYUKNOn7v_odQ8fUMEWWc8ux9dasp9_SfryYplsUPdrV7Z2zTvjYcuzfecjPsjKDAVhDfYiEUrFxBrAOakXhoJDIr8mFevfahkdJPzzCntkqrgt8KY4aIRD6olFZAlHF83TPH3fbL4EHpxBUU; SDR-Application-AFT=CfDJ8MzjMVmpnLpKi5exDubmXfStXUVh1gFAfTk287t86Xy7bocYw6WhG7jiTnmMsSrpJiDg07UjE3fWjt1IVEO7qBUBpDqKW3rHjfJry65-3RDGlw1RmeD4Dz-gAlJB8w6ymX5-O7HuHQO0KfNpQoFWtDE; CUID=c28c3aee-8b3f-4225-9bc4-55002813c7e5_947d7b34-d6be-4083-8388-57276f3fbfb0; CSID=g3qL9RL3%2FXXInBEf%2FBNbXzpO2HdORePUKccHrAaoVA2JJug%2Bwy9U%2BGr%2F%2FlF5SJoigJP2cniHq%2FMha1eAJqNktU8KBvCXEqKA0%2Fst3lKBgvmW%2FY91KSP1G3Fag78mJ2KB10H1TKPENCTgCYb5f%2Fe9xpTKNrHsMApWYJuRRPgj%2BrD2OOCKgtXzF1%2Frg36nywL0VuYz5f%2BLdZID5I2Wy6jDyMz%2BpTqiKi0jyQBBr6vE6Dfau704cNfh1YL89fabPsi3NY2bFjcf13GhzOcWJQ6CWrEqQUPWl%2B9or2D%2Bly0JL%2F8z3VDCd%2FHasLpCUhD7ZcCmxv15R8rnjP8TgqgU1Rh4HyxiK3wVgIINeP%2FtQscUKpLfxPwjrSxNQzZox5LzxYFCBhtjDNybTcqqySuosCtUk%2BWYeP5KymiBq4s%2Bs9cZteG1R6faVaGDfKUSEye2GxLgtLScXlwVf%2BaWkjDtrgNzGteQNKoevyYHZePVMqBBIww8alxm2mE9wPZjj2pyaFsZzsCwt1oWnUzSXFFkjys9KUiRpB%2FWghYUUENKSRxC%2BmHZ7VfCMFRaEmmIo3oGNx%2FfKWGP5n1nM9L52t%2BpKQfY4F0QKQZQgAQUkmbqjvU7TYV8cEb9ns%2BUqw%2FtKOih9VfmKZ35xruNqoE%2B2bGTBQEA0ynT%2FGVM%2BIPvB7BlhpHr1lAoSqNxiP6%2FhG8gMBmGJvndeu7nn51mS1yep8NCXIpRwHx4nXyNEMdqEsSm4QfCdbxkNHbeA%2Bb6CrCEOPhn5o6eeltTb7Yo%2FElyQpeXC0gpbq44W2pXZci41CLqVNDTyomn%2B2hPqSzys1VW4cGi0Mk%2BL%2BcJCmGZXKmaw69iQ6CVXRVhGLhmjWIAnOs%2BO0%2FX43otgO8nhl99H%2FG83ngyvn5E78tN9XvHu2rYqTr89lg%2FpaLJ7etwN5kqPR2GI3UZ8d6w1uSw84lcj2S%2FcLg39aIqpqomm8blSGaAMVri0YiL0YwLemCu2m%2FOz5pKzeDkQgw10ieaeBIdT9OsCnxsPkHne4SiyraBpdbkUaJ0JeBZNQ%3D%3D; CTID=hhWjy3FtBI%2B%2BH34KhCfrwNqmsS96AeOqezXSpiguvcfWT6Vj1QtNuwUCIvIZCmebzvP2JTsKx6oDNfcL7TigYjY8PMj%2BBXnEAvRtsQ0KAwiGUq236NOWkTj5rurGdiwOvotKMfW4RJZyOYXwin%2FkZvBKTGoh5ZY%2Bw5GKkwH0h9An6cq2zJ6EWhKNHCg8EdTqzvBNwYMSme1TrYBorlE19RXQJttrn4w08ltZiys0u3o6%2BJ%2FhsMrqMnQaa%2BKUfNfaC2k46NzZQKL4Kbpv6pBLEtDdc9iJKKU%2BHFUXdRifIPiItlHwZK97lqDAyqPhY83evnF7eL5HyvY7B7RLk6eum5OK2HQaHsaK%2FNU2VO95KOMQFG2yhIpAfmDrX
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header:
"POST /Manage/Message/Announcement/Update HTTP/1.0
Host: manage_us
Connection: close
Content-Length: 2304
Cache-Control: max-age=0
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="106", "Google Chrome";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Origin: http://localhost:9190
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Referer: http://localhost:9190/Manage/Message/Announcement/Edit/a4f91c12-ebd3-4c98-9544-41d3757770bf
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: SDR-Application-AFT=CfDJ8FbhNDhYUKNOn7v_odQ8fUMEWWc8ux9dasp9_SfryYplsUPdrV7Z2zTvjYcuzfecjPsjKDAVhDfYiEUrFxBrAOakXhoJDIr8mFevfahkdJPzzCntkqrgt8KY4aIRD6olFZAlHF83TPH3fbL4EHpxBUU; SDR-Application-AFT=CfDJ8MzjMVmpnLpKi5exDubmXfStXUVh1gFAfTk287t86Xy7bocYw6WhG7jiTnmMsSrpJiDg07UjE3fWjt1IVEO7qBUBpDqKW3rHjfJry65-3RDGlw1RmeD4Dz-gAlJB8w6ymX5-O7HuHQO0KfNpQoFWtDE; CUID=c28c3aee-8b3f-4225-9bc4-55002813c7e5_947d7b34-d6be-4083-8388-57276f3fbfb0; CSID=g3qL9RL3%2FXXInBEf%2FBNbXzpO2HdORePUKccHrAaoVA2JJug%2Bwy9U%2BGr%2F%2FlF5SJoigJP2cniHq%2FMha1eAJqNktU8KBvCXEqKA0%2Fst3lKBgvmW%2FY91KSP1G3Fag78mJ2KB10H1TKPENCTgCYb5f%2Fe9xpTKNrHsMApWYJuRRPgj%2BrD2OOCKgtXzF1%2Frg36nywL0VuYz5f%2BLdZID5I2Wy6jDyMz%2BpTqiKi0jyQBBr6vE6Dfau704cNfh1YL89fabPsi3NY2bFjcf13GhzOcWJQ6CWrEqQUPWl%2B9or2D%2Bly0JL%2F8z3VDCd%2FHasLpCUhD7ZcCmxv15R8rnjP8TgqgU1Rh4HyxiK3wVgIINeP%2FtQscUKpLfxPwjrSxNQzZox5LzxYFCBhtjDNybTcqqySuosCtUk%2BWYeP5KymiBq4s%2Bs9cZteG1R6faVaGDfKUSEye2GxLgtLScXlwVf%2BaWkjDtrgNzGteQNKoevyYHZePVMqBBIww8alxm2mE9wPZjj2pyaFsZzsCwt1oWnUzSXFFkjys9KUiRpB%2FWghYUUENKSRxC%2BmHZ7VfCMFRaEmmIo3oGNx%2
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http cleanup add: 000055E39DBC47A8
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 get rr peer, try: 1
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 stream socket 21
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 epoll add connection: fd:21 ev:80002005
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 connect to 172.18.0.5:80, fd:21 #7
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http upstream connect: -2
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 posix_memalign: 000055E39DBB4010:128 @16
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 event timer add: 21: 60000:8982386
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http finalize request: -4, "/Manage/Message/Announcement/Update?" a:1, c:2
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http request count:2 blk:0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http run request: "/Manage/Message/Announcement/Update?"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http upstream check client, write event:1, "/Manage/Message/Announcement/Update"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http upstream request: "/Manage/Message/Announcement/Update?"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http upstream send request handler
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http upstream send request
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http upstream send request body
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 chain writer buf fl:0 s:3868
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 chain writer buf fl:1 s:2304
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 chain writer in: 000055E39DBC4808
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 writev: 6172 of 6172
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 chain writer out: 0000000000000000
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 event timer del: 21: 8982386
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 event timer add: 21: 60000:8982386
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http upstream request: "/Manage/Message/Announcement/Update?"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http upstream process header
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 malloc: 000055E39DC2DEF0:16384
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 recv: fd:21 170 of 16384
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy status 400 "400 Bad Request"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "Connection: close"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "Date: Sat, 22 Oct 2022 16:45:32 GMT"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "Content-Length: 0"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy header done
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 posix_memalign: 000055E39DBBB430:4096 @16
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 22 Oct 2022 16:45:33 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055E39DBBB450, pos 000055E39DBBB450, size: 190 file: 0, size: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:190
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http cacheable: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http proxy filter init s:400 h:0 c:0 l:0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http upstream process upstream
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe read upstream: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe preread: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe buf free s:0 t:1 f:0 000055E39DC2DEF0, pos 000055E39DC2DF9A, size: 0 file: 0, size: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe length: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe write downstream: 1
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 pipe write downstream done
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 event timer: 21, old: 8982386, new: 8982388
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http upstream exit: 0000000000000000
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 finalize http upstream request: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 finalize http proxy request
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 free rr peer 1 0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 close http upstream connection: 21
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 free: 000055E39DBB4010, unused: 48
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 event timer del: 21: 8982386
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 reusable connection: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http upstream temp fd: -1
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http output filter "/Manage/Message/Announcement/Update?"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http copy filter: "/Manage/Message/Announcement/Update?"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http postpone filter "/Manage/Message/Announcement/Update?" 00007FFD0E8F95E0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055E39DBBB450, pos 000055E39DBBB450, size: 190 file: 0, size: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 0000000000000000, size: 0 file: 0, size: 0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:190
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http write filter limit 2097152
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 writev: 190 of 190
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http write filter 0000000000000000
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http copy filter: 0 "/Manage/Message/Announcement/Update?"
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http finalize request: 0, "/Manage/Message/Announcement/Update?" a:1, c:1
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 set http keepalive handler
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http close request
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 http log handler
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 free: 000055E39DC2DEF0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 free: 000055E39DBB0DE0, unused: 12
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 free: 000055E39DBC3C50, unused: 112
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 free: 000055E39DBBA420, unused: 64
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 free: 000055E39DBBB430, unused: 3222
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 free: 000055E39DB9A1B0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 hc free: 0000000000000000
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 hc busy: 000055E39DBB4368 1
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 free: 000055E39DC1DEE0
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 reusable connection: 1
2022/10/22 16:45:33 [debug] 25#25: *3 event timer add: 20: 65000:8987388
```

I have renamed my .NET Core antiforgery token to not include dots or underscores.

However, I am still stuck on this issue.

This is my nginx conf:

```
upstream gateway_us {
    server sdr_gateway.web;
}
upstream manage_us {
    server sdr_manage.web;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;
    server_tokens off;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
# Allow larger than normal headers
large_client_header_buffers 4 64k;
proxy_buffers         8 16k;  # Buffer pool = 8 buffers of 16k
proxy_buffer_size     16k;    # 16k of buffers from pool used for headers

    error_log /var/log/nginx/sdr-fe-nginx-error.log debug;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/sdr-fe-nginx-access.log;

    ignore_invalid_headers off;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    location /{
        proxy_pass http://gateway_us/;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_pass_header Authorization; 
    }
    location /Gateway/{
        proxy_pass http://gateway_us/;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_pass_header Authorization; 
    }
    location /Manage/{
        proxy_pass http://manage_us/Manage/;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_pass_header Authorization; 
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I noticed that the issue is because my cookies are being cut. Not all of it is being sent. I even added additional buffers but the same issue happens.

Comment: Does this help: [How to fix nginx throws 400 bad request headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315832/how-to-fix-nginx-throws-400-bad-request-headers-on-any-header-testing-tools) ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this config,to enable keepalive connections.

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "";
```

It solves my problem